# First order differential equation $y'y^2=y+xy'$, switching dependent and independent variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation $y'y^2=y+xy'$. I notice that the differential is not in the general form of first order linear equations which is $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$. In fact the above equation is not linear.

I read that I have to switch the dependent and independent variable of the problem and then the problem will turn into linear first order differential equation. I don't quite understand the concept of switching dependent and independent variable, can someone explain?

Comment: Direct integration yields $y^3-3xy=3k$ for some constant $k$, hence $x=\frac{y^2}{3}-\frac{k}{y}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, what do you mean by switching variables, but if you simply need to solve it, here's what I'd do
$$
y'y^2 = y + xy' \implies \left(\frac {y^3}3 \right)' = (xy)' \implies \frac {y^3}3 = xy + C
$$
You can leave it as it is in the form of implicit function, or solve for $x$
$$
x = \frac {y^3 - 3C}{3y}
$$

Answer (score 2):

To follow on from the comment above. Two things to know 
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} g(y) = \dfrac{dg}{dy}y'
$$
And
$$
f'(x)y + f(x)y' = (f(x)y)'
$$
Always look for tricks like the above when solving (or trying to solve) odes.